# Does adding a column to a cassandra table complete instantly?

Tags: cassandra, schema

We plan to add a column of type list to an existing cassandra table which data file size is about 350 GB.  We can temporarily halt all the read/write for a few minutes while applying the schema change.

Our understanding is that cassandra does not lock a table when applying schema changes, but to be sure our DBA wants to do an experiment on a table with datafile at 25 GB in size. However it will take 3-4 weeks to grow in such size on a small server where a non-production cassandra server is running (having more concurrent inserts starts to cause time out issues).

Does anyone know that adding a column to an existing cassandra table returns promptly regardless the underlying data file size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a column in Cassandra is just an addition of the column's meta-information to internal table that keeps schema information. No modification of existing data happens when this change is done - Cassandra will simply put null instead of the column value when there is no data for it on the disk (for any column, not only what was added) - this happens when the data is returned to caller, not by adding null to the files.

Similarly, deletion of the column doesn't modify the existing data - instead a new entry is added to `system_schema.dropped_columns` table, and corresponding data is filtered out after they are read from the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  We applied the schema changes adding a new column and it completed promptly, also without affecting ongoing read or write.

Comment: “Cassandra will simply put null instead...”: I know you know, but I would clarify that this relates to reading a row that has no values set for that column from disk (or the value was null already, eg a delete, an expired value, an explicit null insert), and that Cassandra doesn’t “add a column with null values” when adding a new column.